# Read an Array inside a json

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I think I have a problem with serialized name. I have this JSON:

```
{
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
        {"Name": "test", "Family": "test"},
        {"Name": "test2", "Family": "test2"}
    ],
    "item_page": 2
}
```

and a class :

```
public class UserFetch(){

@SerializedName("current_page")
@Expose
private int currentPage;

@SerializedName("item_page")
@Expose
private int item_page;

@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private list<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

public UserFetch(){
}
//getter and setter and another constructor not mentioned

}
```

and the user class is serialized too :

```
public class User(){

@SerializedName("Name")
@Expose
private String Name;

@SerializedName("Family")
@Expose
private String Family;

public User(){
}
//getter and setter and another constructor not mentioned

}
```

When I call json wia retrofit and get data(Successfull and another variables are working like `current_page`) but the array not working and when I call an item of array , IndexOutofBounds shows.

**Edit :** it's how I call the array object:

```
Call<UserFetch> call = userservice.getAllUsers();
call.enqueue(new Callback<UserFetch>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<UserFetch> call, Response<UserFetch> response) {
        if(response.isSuccessful()){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SuccessFull!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), response.body().getUsers().get(0).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "unSuccess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<StoreFetch> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failure : " + t.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Write your User class inside UserFetch class, like shown below:

```
public class UserFetch() {

    @SerializedName("current_page")
    @Expose
    public int currentPage;

    @SerializedName("item_page")
    @Expose
    public int item_page;

    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    public list<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    public class User(){

        @SerializedName("Name")
        @Expose
        public String Name;

        @SerializedName("Family")
        @Expose
        public String Family;

    }

}
```

Instead of:

```
if(response.isSuccessful()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SuccessFull!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), response.body().getUsers().get(0).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Your variables must be public as shown, then,

Instead of:

```
if(response.isSuccessful()){
        UserFetch userFetch = response.body();
        List<UserFetch.User> userList = userFetch.users;
        for (UserFetch.User user : userList) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "name : " + user.Name + " family: " + user.Family, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

If you want a specific name and family data, you can use the traditional for loop.

Hope this will work. Any doubt you can comment below.

Comment: how write User class inside UserFetch class could you explain?

Comment: can you show me User and UserFetch both class coding please? I mean Full class @VahidH

Comment: User and UserFetch class Added!

Comment: Unfortunely not woking!

Comment: @VahidH this line `List<UserFetch.User> userList = userFetch.data;` change it to `List<UserFetch.User> userList = userFetch.users;` ... Now it should work

Comment: @VahidH Edited my answer, just copy and paste it, it should work fine.

Comment: I tested in my system bro, How can it show index out of bounds. Okay, can you paste whatever you have written in code.

Comment: my real code is too much variable but the syntax is like this . do you have any way to stay in contact with you?

Comment: _Your variables must be public as shown_ OP is already using getter() methods (check code comments in `UserFetch` and `User` classes) to access member variables, hence do not need to use `public` access specifiers for member variables.

Comment: @Shashanth Rather than commenting on the answer, it will be better if you check and solve his issue. BTW public variables also works.\

Comment: _BTW public variables also works_ I nowhere said that it doesn't work. I saw "Your variables _must_ be public as shown" in your answer. So, I commented on your answer.

Comment: Oh, Sorry.. Perhaps I was mistaken